# Venn diagram with item labels and 4 groups of data

Tags: python, r, visualization, venn-diagram

I would like to generate a venn diagram with either R or Python for 4 groups of data that contains item labels. I would like the size (or position) of the ellipses to change depending on the content so that all words are easy to read, do not overlap with each other and are contained within ellipses.

I got good results by writing the code below. However, if I add more item labels (in each category AA, BB, CC or DD) to be displayed the words go over the borders of the ellipses which I do not like as it makes the labels difficult to read.  Can the size of the ellipses or their position be customised somehow to account for the large data content? Thank you.

`library(ggvenn)`
`library(RColorBrewer)`

`AA <- c("hi","foo", "bar","yep","woo","hoo")`
`BB <- c("baa","yep", "woo","yes")`
`CC <- c("yes","foo","hi","woo", "huh")`
`DD <- c("baa","foo","yep","woo","yes")`

`x <- list(AA=AA , BB=BB , CC=CC, DD=DD)`

`ggvenn(x, show_elements = T,text_size=2, label_sep = "\n", fill_color = brewer.pal(name="Set2",n=4))`